# ASP.NET MVC 4's SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net, simplemembership

Has anyone succeeded in getting SimpleMemberShip (WebMatrix etc) to work with Oracle? I'm using EF 5 against Oracle and it works but when it comes to this:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(conn, "Oracle.DataAccess.Client", "USERPROFILE", "USERID", "USERNAME", autoCreateTables: false);
```

This fails saying that the USERPROFILE table cannot be found.

I'm beginning to think that it is not compatible with Oracle's EF connection string.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

> Note that SimpleMembership still requires some flavor of SQL Server - it won't work with MySQL, NoSQL databases, etc. You can take a look at the code in WebMatrix.WebData.dll using a tool like ILSpy if you'd like to see why - there are places where SQL Server specific SQL statements are being executed, especially when creating and initializing tables. It seems like you might be able to work with another database if you created the tables separately, but I haven't tried it and it's not supported at this point.

Unless that has changed, the answer is likely still no.

Comment: Thanks...I was digging around and all....sigh. Do you have any recommendations of Membership to use for Oracle via MVC?

Comment: Regular asp.net membership will work, I believe oracle ships a provider